Nuxt 3 in Docker: environment variables accessible everywhere but not in nuxt.config.ts
I'm trying to move a nuxt 3 app to using docker-compose.
I read in the documentation that .env files are not read by nuxt in production.
So I'm trying to add them to the environment directive in my docker-compose.yml.
This works for most parts of my app, like on the server.
But specifically in my nuxt.config.ts where I need to specify my google client id for oauth, it does not work.
// nuxt.config.ts

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: false },
    ssr: true,
    modules: ["nuxt-vue3-google-signin"],
    compatibilityDate: "2024-09-04",

    googleSignIn: {
        clientId: process.env.NUXT_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, 
// This is not recognized in production, the app fails to initialize with the 500 error that the clientID is missing
// I also tried leaving it as empty string and using "NUXT_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID" in my docker-compose.yml under environment
// and I tried using `import "dotenv/config";` and `require("dotenv").config();` at the top of this file as suggested by a similar problem someone had
    },

    css: ["~/assets/css/main.css"],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
});


# docker-compose.yml

services:
  my-nuxt-app:
    image: ghcr.io/me/my-nuxt-app:latest
    container_name: my-nuxt-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6000:6000"
    env_file: ".env"
    environment:
      - NUXT_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}


// server/api/some-endpoint.ts

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    console.log(process.env.NUXT_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID) // this works as expected
});

